# Python selection of multiple criteria and correct formatting?

Tags: python, where-clause

I have a script that classifies vegetation based off a species field (and a few other fields).  I have found that there is an error in the original dataset that is causing a few of the records to be misclassified.   I am writing a section in my code to find those records after the classification has occurred (because they won't fix the original layers for a while).  Basically I am trying to select those records with NS present that do not have a Fornon of 20.  I am running the script in ArcGIS as a scripting tool and keep getting syntax error.  Sometime the little things mess me up like formatting.  Any suggestions on how to fix this or alternate workflows would be appreciated

Tried doing the selection and saving the expression and copying it into code but formatting is different.  I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 on a windows 7 64bit system.  I use IDLE to edit my script but then load it to script tool in ArcGIS

```
arcpy.AddMessage('> Finding Norway Spruce plantations that do not have a fornon of 20 ...')
shapefileFC = comb_raster
where_fornon1  = ("species" = 'NS04BS02WS02BF02' or "species" = 'NS05BS05' or "species" = 'NS05RS05' or "species" = 'NS06BS02BF02' or "species" = 'NS06BS03WS01' or "species" = 'NS06BS04' or "species" = 'NS06RS03BF01' or "species" = 'NS06TL03BS01' or "species" = 'NS06WS04' or "species" = 'NS07BS03' or "species" = 'NS07RS03' or "species" = 'NS07WS03' or "species" = 'NS08BF02' or "species" = 'NS08BS01BF601' or "species" = 'NS08BS02' or "species" = 'NS08RP02' or "species" = 'NS08RS01BF01' or "species" = 'NS08TL01BS01' or "species" = 'NS09BF01' or "species" = 'NS09BS01' or "species" = 'NS09RS01' or "species" = 'NS09WS01' or "species" = 'NS10' and TargetMap+'_fornon' != '20')
fields      = ('L06', 'species')
# row id:         0       1
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefileFC, fields, where_fornon1) as Cursor:
    for row in Cursor:
        SPECIES = row[1]
        if len(SPECIES) < 4:
            row[0] = 'No species data'
        else:
            if Spp(ex_) >= 10:
                if Spp(ns_) >= 50:
                   row[0]  ='NS plt'
            else:
                   row[0]  ='Unk plt'
```

What I hope is that it will select all those error records and write "NS plt" into the L06 field.  This way even if it gets misclassified we can catch and fix it.

Comment: I think you can see in the formatting of your question how something has gone funny with the quotes. Check the end of the `where_fornon1` line, it looks like that might be messed up

Comment: It's better to use a more powerful python IDE, like Spyder (which comes with anaconda), or pycharm. This way, you can execute your script in those IDE. It can save time from formatting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think where_fornon1 is a sql where clase and needs to be a string.

Maybe try

```
where_fornon1 = """( "species" = 'value1' or .... )"""
```

otherwise python is trying to evaluate it as python code, which will definiately give you syntax errors, so no surprise you get a syntax error. You may also need to delete the double quotes around the `species` fields, since I dont know if thats valid sql.

Comment: So far so good, no more syntax error, will see if it is doing its job.  Thanks